# Weird Wi-Fi connection issue on Linux Mint 16

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, router

We have a LG-R590 laptop and an AirTies 5343 WLAN router at home. When the router broadcasts the SSID of the wireless home network I cannot connect to the network automatically, I have to connect to the network as if its SSID were hidden.

When I set the router to hide the SSID of the home network the wireless network browser in Mint MATE is able to see and connect to the network. However, in this case the SSID is hidden in Windows as expected and leads to undesired effort to get connected to the internet on other computers, and I am concerned about this since my parents are not that much tech-savvy. I have provided a screenshot of the modem settings (saved) when the computer is able to locate and connect to the network on Linux Mint 16 MATE. How can I restore default behaviour on this computer so that it sees and is able to connect to the network when SSID is broadcasted?

**Details:**

Linux Mint Mate 16 32-bit

LG R590 Notebook

**Output of lspci**

02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8191SEvB Wireless LAN Controller (rev 10)

03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8131 Gigabit Ethernet (rev c0)

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think it's a wise thing to publish your WLAN password here. You certainly should change it as soon as possible now.

Comment: Consider the fact that everything ELSE connects just fine when the SSID is NOT hidden... the problem is your Mint installation.  Figure out what's non-standard there, and you'll solve your problem.  It's not the router, it's not mom's computer, and it's not your parents.

Comment: @lornix Well what may have went wrong in your opinion?

Comment: @celtschk I thought it would not pose any hazard since the probability that someone in the vicinity of our network would read it is relatively low anyhow I can change it.

Comment: You haven't indicated what desktop you're using (if any), what settings you've selected, what version you're using, and whether it's sunny outside or not.  _something_ is different about your particular Mint setup which is causing it to operate slightly different.  But you're trying to say it's the router.  Which it cannot be, since many other standard devices can access it with standard setups.  Perhaps it __is__ the router, but experience shows that it's _very_ unlikely and would be inappropriate to start there. Not trying to be mean.

Comment: If you ask the desktop environment its the default MATE shipped with Linux Mint 16. Which setting should I provide so that you can provide some help?